# What is address[]?

Tags: solidity

What is address[] in solidity?

I found it in a tutorial video I watched but I am unable to find any information about this on internet! Does anyone knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`address[]` is a type, an array of addresses. You can think of it as a list of addresses.

The square brackets, `[]`, are use to specify that this type is an array.

You can create an array of many things, like an array of `uint256` numbers:

`uint256[] numbers;`

And many more with a similar syntax.

Many languages use the `[]` to create or declare an array. Like Javascript: `const numbers = [];`. We can usually initiate an array with values, like in js: `const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];`. In Solidity it would look like this for an array of `uint256` numbers in storage: `uint256[] numbers = [1,2,3,4];`

In your case, an array of addresses can be declared as a state variable as follows:

```js
address[] admins;
```

And then, in another function you can add addresses to that array:

```js
function addAdmin(address adminAddress) public onlyOwner {
   admins.push(adminAddress);
}
```

Of if you know the address before hand you can hard code them while you declare the array of addresses, like this:

```js
address[] admins = [0x66B0b1d2930059407DcC30F1A2305435fc37315E, 0x6827b8f6cc60497d9bf5210d602C0EcaFDF7C405];
```

Arrays are really useful to hold a collection of things, objects, numbers, addresses, strings, etc.

We access arrays by index, starting at index 0 for the first element in most programming languages. If I want to access the first element of the array, then I do:

```
admins[0];
```

For the second:

```js
admins[1];
```

And so on. Or in a loop:

```js
for(uint256 i = 0; i < admins.length; i++) {
  address adminAddress = admins[i];
  // ...
  // do something with adminAddress
}
```

And so on.

Solidity has many rules for arrays. State and local arrays are usually declared differently and used a bit differently in some cases. To learn more about them you can check the documentation: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#arrays

I hope it has helped.

Answer (score 2):

In Solidity, `address[]` is an array consisting of addresses.

See: [How can I instantiate an array of addresses?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2164/how-can-i-instantiate-an-array-of-addresses)

Answer (score 0):

In Solidity, address[] is an array of type address. An address in Solidity is a data type that represents a 20-byte Ethereum address. Arrays in Solidity are a type of data structure that allows you to store and manage a collection of data. In this case, an address[] array would be used to store a collection of Ethereum addresses.